# How to include a binary file with Android NDK project?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, adb

I know its bad practice but whats the best way to include a binary file with Android NDK project? The file should be executable with the system command.

I don't want to copy it manually copy to the device but distribute it within my .apk.

Comment: Copy the executable to res/raw as part of your build process.  Resources there are accessible from the application and are copied with the .apk

Comment: running system(command) or popen(command) freezes now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to rename the executable to `"lib_myexecutable_.so"` and put it in  `libs/armeabi` folder under your project root: this file will be extracted by the Package Manager on the device to `/data/data/your.package.full.name/lib`, with executable permissions.

If you use `ndk-build` to build `myexecutable`, all `./libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)` directory will be refreshed.

To automate the rename operation, use the following in your `Android.mk`:

```
... # whatever you have to define the executable
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
# immediately after this,
all: .libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib_myexecutable_.so

.libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib_myexecutable_.so: $(LOCAL_INSTALLED)
<tab>$(call host-mv, $<, $@)
```

Comment: compilation with your suggestion deteles the "lib_myexecutable_.so". Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This happens if `myexecutable` is built by `ndk-build`. You can automate the process in this case, see the ***Update***.